# How to compute the conditional probability distribution with given joint distributions and marginal distribution?

Tags: matlab, statistics

I am trying to compute the conditional distribution p(a|c) with given equation consists of a set of marginal distribution and joint distribution. The variables A,B,C have the Markov property A->B->C.

[eq1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99oXu.jpg)

Dimensions of each distribution is

p(c) -> 20x1 vector

p(b,a) -> 20x20 matrix

p(c|b) -> 20x20 matrix  (although I am not sure this part though, each p(a) p(b) 
p(c) is supposed to be 20x1 vector. Could you confirm this? Basically I am not sure if this conditional distribution p(c|b) should have a dimension of 20x20 ).

I was trying to calculate this by using for loop in MATLAB such that (here, p(a|c) = pabc, p(c|b) = pcbb, p(c) = pc, p(b,a) = pba)

```
for i = 1:length(pc)
     ThisPc = pc(i);
     ThisSum = 0;
     for ii = 1:size(pcbb,1)
          ThisPba = (pba(ii,:))';
          ThisPcbb = (pcbb(ii,:))';
          ThisSum = ThisSum + (ThisPba.*ThisPcbb);
     end
     pabc(i,:) = (ThisSum./ThisPc)';
end
```

As you might notice, I already have p(c), p(b,a), p(c|b), although I am not sure about p(c|b). Could you confirm if my code is consistent with a given equation above and each variable's dimension is correct?? Thank you!

Comment: are you asking about Bayes rule?

Comment: No, it's not about the Bayes rule (as far as I know). I am sure Bayes rule is related somehow, but I don't think it's a main tool in this equation.

Comment: Are you asking "what is the conditional distribution?"? Because it looks like you don't know what it is. This seems more of a question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). There's not really anything to compute here.